# How to Setup a Rotating Gateway for List of Proxies

Tags: http, proxy, gateway, socks

I have a list of proxies both **Http** and **Socks**. These proxies are Authenicated via IP which means they can be access from one IP only.

I am trying to Create a Gateway like a **SuperProxy** which can route traffic through them.

Challenge here is the Proxy list is partically dynamic means these can be changed to new IPs.

Is there are tool/opensourced code that fulfill the requirements.

Second challenge is the Socks proxies. Which can't be used via HTTP clients.

Is there a way to tunnel HTTP Traffic via Socks proxies

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are looking for something like nginx/openresty. with which you can proxy tcp/http and add restricting policy to the proxy.

1. to proxy socket checkout the docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html, you need binray with stream core module buildin.
2. to add restricting policy checkout https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/.
3. with openresty,ip can maintained in source file which written by lua

Comment: The Aim is to create a Gateway to tunnel traffic throw a single IP to which the Proxies are authenicated to.